# Should I create a builder for a Class wich has large number of required attributes

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

If I have a class with a fairly large number of attributes, say 10, all of which are required [non null or non optional] to construct the entity correctly, then what is the best way to instantiate this class?

- Should I create a Builder with no args constructor which has
  withers for all the attributes and check for "non null" in
  the private constructor of the entity being constructed

  **OR**
- should I have a public constructor with all the 10 arguments and create
  NO Builder?

Having a builder makes the client code look cleaner while having an all args public constructor conveys the message that all the arguments are required [say, I annotate all the parameters with `@javax.annotations.Nonnull` annotation]

How should I decide?

For example,

```
/**
  * PLEASE SET SOME VALUE FOR ALL THE ATTRIBUTES!
  */
Class A {

   private final String a1;
   ...
   private final TypeN an;

   private A(Builder builder) {
      // copy all all the parameters
      this.a1 = builder.a1;
      ...
      this.an = builder.an;

      // null checks
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(this.a1);
      ...
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(this.an);
   }

   public static class Builder{
       private String a1;
       ...
       private TypeN an;

       public Builder withA1(String a1) {
          this.a1 = a1;
          return this;
       }

       // other withers

       public A build() {
          return new A(this);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should probably decompose more. Rather than passing in 10 parameters, you should probably be grouping some of those parameters together into 1 object, then passing in that object as a parameter. You could probably cut 10 parameters down to 3, allowing you to easily use a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the Builder is the right choice. If you have one book on your shelf while writing Java it should be Josh Bloch's [*Effective Java*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683). In the 2nd Edition he has a Static Builder pattern.

There are two other reasons not mentioned here for doing this:

- the parameters are descriptive in a builder, instead of just passing an int, you have a builder method called 'weight' or 'height' (whatever)
- the whole point is that it encourages immutability

The idea that it's nothing more than syntactic sugar is absurd. If you have a setter on all 10 params, you are not doing OO: anyone can just change anything about the instance at will at any point in its lifecycle.

Comment: I am not saying that I will have setters in the Entity. they will be in the Static Builder.. Let me edit the question a bit

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what you should do. So your question is why do this rather than a huge constructor? I think that's what I tried to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor sounds as better option since it will enforce you to provide all required parameters and you can run non null checks in them. Having a constructor with a lot of parameters is usually a sign of bad design. Maybe you would think of a better way to structure your class. Consider grouping some of the parameters as new class ( if they have logical connection). Having this you can create few smaller objects and then pass them as parameters to your constructor. You can modify the getters/setters to get what is necessary from these objects.

Comment: I understand that an entity with large number of attributes can sometimes mean that the design is not proper but assuming that all the entities in this world can be defined by a small number of attributes doesn't sound practical. How many small classes will you create? Will it not be unmaintainable to  have a deep hierarchy of small small entities?

Comment: I can agree with you but still that does not mean that he/she should not think for a way to group some of the parameters if possible. Obviously this may not work in all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your blueprint is a strong candidate to be refactored; rest assure that, if for some reason, you have those many members the class is modeled (most of the times) wrongly.

Leaving that asides, I'm not sure how you can go with a *builder* since you must enforce that all members must be present and with some value, so it's more likely that you put them all also in the builder's constructor itself because all members are required. Being said that, IMHO the 10-members constructor in that case makes more sense.

<del>A builder in my opinion gives you "syntactic sugar", nothing else...but definitely not in your case.</del>

Comment: What if I let my Builder have a no args constructor? I will put a nice documentation comment on the Builder's constructor or on the Entity class itself?

I will put the checks inside Main entity's private constructor!

Will it not be a good trade off between readability vs. fail fast?

Comment: And what would be the default value for your members? Didn't you say they all must have a value? You can do it, but it only makes sense (for your case) if you assign "something" by default when you instantiate your object and there no value was provided (more likely `null`)

Comment: added a simple code to explain how I would write my builder and entity.

And, just for the sake of discussion, let's assume that there is no way to further refactor this entity! :D

Comment: @DhrumilUpadhyaya yes...that could be a way. In fact, I encourage you to do it...and it's valid since you want that `A` must conform to those rules. Additionally, `this.a1 = Preconditions.checkNotNull(builder.a1);` is simpler, since that (ugly) static method call will give you back the reference of `builder.a1` if it is not `null`